# Как jquery скриптом удалять элементы, содержащие в id "block"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как это решить:
Допустим у меня есть span-ы с id "blockquote", "block" и мне нужно удалить ВСЕ элементы, содержащие в id "block". Как это сделать?

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <span id="blockquote">это должно удалиться</span><br>
        <span id="block">это должно удалиться</span><br>
        <span id="vlock">это <b>НЕ</b> должно удалиться</span>
        <script>
           let name = $("span");
           if (span.attr("id").split("block").length >= 1) {
              name.remove(); 
           }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

, но это не сработало. Возможно из-за моего "мастерства".

Comment: "Я перепробовал много вариантов, так и не понял как это сделать. Ни google, ни яндекс не помог" ..... это так смешно читать если честно

Comment: показывай что пробовал и что не помогло

Comment: let name = $("span")

if (span.attr("id").split("block").length >= 1) {
    name.remove();
}

Comment: В отрыве от html - код не особо что говорит.....добвать html и js код **прямо в вопрос** и не забудь написать **что именнно** не работает в нём

Comment: интересно, какой там  мыслительный процесс происходит, что такой код генерируется.

Comment: я просто только начал изучать тему js, jq . спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю должно быть что-то такое:

```js
let name = $("span");
name.each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("id").includes('block')) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="blockquote">это должно удалиться</span><br>
<span id="block">это должно удалиться</span><br>
<span id="vlock">это <b>НЕ</b> должно удалиться</span>
```

Суть: выбираем все span и пробегаемся по ним циклом, внутри цикла проверяем если у  текущего элемента, на котором сейчас во время итерации находится цикл `$(this)`, то берём значение атрибута и проверяем на содержание в нём текста. Если есть, то его же и удаляем, опять же через `$(this)`

Comment: `$("[id*=block]").remove()` ?

Comment: я уже не помню) наверное)